# When does hajj become farz?

Tags: fard, hajj

As we know there is a certain rule when Zakat becomes Farz. But I suppose in case of Hajj, it cannot be that strict because the cost to travel to the Holy Makka differs from place to place.

So what is the rule regarding Hajj becoming obligatory?

Comment: i think some of the reasons why hajj is so lenient is because of cost, not travel distance

Comment: @NesreenA: You are right. I am editing the question.

Comment: It's not just cost, but other physical limitations. Only a certain number of people are allowed to participate in Hajj every year, and often the oldest (or richest) people are prioritized. It's also why being able to perform Umrah does not make Hajj compulsory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditions which when met, make Hajj fardh for you:

1. Being Muslim
2. Being of sound mind
3. Being an adult
4. Being free
5. Being able to do Hajj

Click [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/41957) to see the full fatwa.

Just in case that link stops working, please see the edits of this answer for the full fatwa.

Comment: Please summarize the relevant portions of the answer, and leave a link to the source for elaboration.

Comment: Doing that is not a problem for me, but it's not always the best thing to do considering the volatility of the web, i.e. links can be taken down at the source.  So generally it's best to show the full content just incase that happens.

Comment: @oshirowanen: just another explanation. Should not we attempt to go for hajj the very first year we become eligible? Is this allowed to wait for future?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you meet most of the standard criteria, so the real major thing to consider is being able to financially support it.

> Hajj is obligatory on a person who has the financial means to travel to Makkah and is able to maintain himself there and his dependants (if any) at home. As for other debts, if a person is heavily indebted and his liabilities exceed his assets, Hajj is not compulsory upon that person. If he fulfils his monthly commitments and his creditors do not have any arrears claim against him, he will not be infringing on the rights of his creditors by performing Hajj on condition that he is sincere in fulfilling the remaining amount according to the commitments. If the creditors have arrears claims against him, he will be infringing on their rights by performing Hajj. Hence, he cannot perform Hajj unless he receives the prior consent of his creditors claiming arrears from him. ([Source](http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=7&ID=2882&CATE=1))

Most people will never be free from debt, so it's difficult to consider the ruling on whether they can afford it. Some things are required to live, such as a house, maybe a business/job, which can get in the way of performing hajj. Scholars have conflicting opinions on whether someone who saves money to get married does not need to perform Hajj first.

But generally, it's agreed that if you have manageable debts, if your creditors allow you to do so, and if don't need to work in that period of time to survive, it becomes compulsory.